# How to show all records in database to JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

Excuse me. I want to show all records in JTable. But I get confused because my coding just show 1 record. When I click it again, that just show same records.
Can you help me how to get all records?

```
try {

            Statement stmt;
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM menu");

            if (rs.next()) {
                String menu_id = rs.getString("menu_id");
                String menu_type = rs.getString("menu_type");
                String menu_cat = rs.getString("menu_cat");
                String menu_name = rs.getString("menu_name");
                String menu_price = rs.getString("menu_price");

                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tblMenu.getModel();
                model.addRow(new Object[]{menu_id, menu_type, menu_cat, menu_name, menu_price});
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed " + e);
        }
```

I have no Idea how to code it. Thank you

Comment: "*But I get confused because my coding just show 1 record*" why do you think your code should put all records in table? Which part of your code you think should ensure that?

Comment: because I want to show menu, so I must show it all. So, the cashier will get easier to do it. @Pshemo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
if (rs.next())
```

to

```
while (rs.next())
```

to run to the code block not just once, but till the end of the `ResultSet`.

It should actually look like this

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tblMenu.getModel();
while (rs.next()) {
    String menu_id = rs.getString("menu_id");
    String menu_type = rs.getString("menu_type");
    String menu_cat = rs.getString("menu_cat");
    String menu_name = rs.getString("menu_name");
    String menu_price = rs.getString("menu_price");

    model.addRow(new Object[]{menu_id, menu_type, menu_cat, menu_name, menu_price});
}
```

Comment: And don't create a new `DefaultTableModel` with the `while` loop

Comment: If I remove it, the code will ask me create field / class "model" @MadProgrammer

Comment: @enjeru Yes, but you don't need to create a new `DefaultTableModel` on each iteration of the loop, which would have occurred had you just simply replaced the `if` with ` while`. The update to the answer illustrates the correct idea

Comment: Ah. I get it. Sorry, I forgot if I put it in loop statement -_- @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        String[] cols={"id","type","cat","name","price"};
        ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String menu_id = rs.getString("menu_id");
            String menu_type = rs.getString("menu_type");
            String menu_cat = rs.getString("menu_cat");
            String menu_name = rs.getString("menu_name");
            String menu_price = rs.getString("menu_price");
            list.add(new String[]{menu_id, menu_type, menu_cat, menu_name, menu_price});
        }

        String[][] elts= new String[list.size()][];
        elts = list.toArray(elts);
        JTable table = new JTable(elts,cols);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,  JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
```

Comment: I had to do the same with database and that is what i did. The main advantage is that you can see the column names on top of the table

Answer (score 0):

You have used `if(rs.next())` you know that if condition checked if it is `true` or `false`.

`rs.next()`

shifts the cursor to the next row of the result set from the database and returns true if there is any row, otherwise false. In combination with the if statement (instead of the while) this means that you expecting in only one row. simply,

`rs.next()`

check for next row if it is exist `if` condition passed and do the code block and get out from the block run the rest of the code.

As to the concrete question about iterate through the database table and add all to the jTable. **You only have to change one keyword**,

`if` to `while`

What happens when you use `while` keyword instead `if` keyword is that `rs.next()` check for next row and if it is true then condition true for `while` loop and go through the code block and when block is finish again check for next row. Likewise go through the all rows in your table and condition will fail after last row.