# JTable records not displayed

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to display the records on `JTable` when the frame is loaded, but the records didn't display. This is what I've tried so far:

```
public void load() {
  try {
    Connection con1;
    PreparedStatement insert;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javapos","root","");
    insert = con1.prepareStatement("SELECT name,status FROM category");
    ResultSet Rs = insert.executeQuery();
    while(Rs.next()) {
      DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
      String name = Rs.getString("name");
      String status = Rs.getString("status");                 
      model.addRow(new Object[]{name,status });                               
    }
    jTable1.setModel(model);                       
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Failed " + e);
  }             
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are not getting the model of the table in the correct way. Try:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tblMenu.getModel();
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151444/how-to-show-all-records-in-database-to-jtable) link to get more information about it.

Comment: Did you checked the answer, did you get it?